# Show datetime picker with time

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I have a datetime picker, but it only allow me to pick the date and not the time. Is there a way to put the time selection?

Model

```
 [Display(Name = "Start")]
 [DataType(DataType.Date)]
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime BookingStartDate { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<input asp-for="BookingStartDate" min="@DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")" asp-format="{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}" class="form-control" />
```

[image]

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes it is. That's the firefox date picker.

Comment: Ah my bad, that's been given a UI update since I last saw it :)

Comment: No worries (Firefox is my bestie)

Comment: Try: `<input type="datetime-local"..........` which is the 'new' type for datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the `asp-for` tag helper, you can change the `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` attribute of BookingStartDate to `[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]` and the page should render the input tag with date and time.